# error launching the android app

Tags: android, error-handling

I just started learning android via the udacity 'android development for beginners' course and they asked us to make an a coffee ordering app.I pasted the MainActivity code given and clicked on run.the app got installed on my phone but doesn't launch.

**Error Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: your Activity in your pakAGE PATH EXIST?

Comment: Please ensure that you have MainActivity in your root java folder. If it is not in the root folder copy that particular package name and paste it on the name field of the activity on your AndroidManifest file

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `MainActivity.java` file in your project. Please insert Activity name correctly instead red text in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

MEntion pacakge name before class name like this...

`com.example.abhishek.justjava.MainActivity`

and also make sure you **activity** is present in the right destination with same name....
and plz cross check the **package name** if you have kept **abhishek** in package name or not....

also include

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

Comment: activity is present in the right destination with the same name and yes my package name is abhishek